# How do I alias a PowerShell script to be called from prompt?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have a PowerShell script that opens all files and programs related to my development environment. Rather than typing

```
> &.\mysetup.ps1
```

is there some way I can alias it to just type

```
> gosetup
```

?

Ideally I'll use this functionality for other PowerShell scripts as well! For reference, I want to run these commands from the Git PowerShell window.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- First you need to set up your PowerShell profile, if you haven't done so already.
- Create a directory where you want to keep your aliased scripts (I use C:\ps).
- In your profile, add the following lines:

  ```
  $ps_script_dir = "C:\path\to\scripts"

  New-Alias <alias name> $ps_script_dir\<script name>
  ```
- Open a new shell, and you should be able to call your script by its alias.

**Update / Additional Information**

- The following is in response to the OP's comment, below.

If you want to simply assign a one-liner, or a short snip of code to an alias, you don't need to put it into a script file, as described above, you can simply create a function in your profile:

```
function someUsefulOneliner
{
    # Your one-liner goes here
}

set-item -path alias:<alias name> -value someUsefulOneliner
```

Comment: I have a follow-up, is it possible to alias a PS command? I tried "New-Alias", but the command won't run. I want to add an alias for this: `ls -in *.sln -r | select -first 1 | %{ ii $_.FullName }`

Comment: @sheldo Yes - that's certainly possible.  See update to solution.

Comment: These days you can make the second line, "set-alias aliasname -value fnname"